# Estimating a spectral gap

Tags: matrix-theory, matrices, spectral-gap

Suppose you have a real positive definite matrix $A$ who eigenvalues are $\lambda_{1} \leq \lambda_{2} \leq \ldots \leq \lambda_{n}$. I am interested in bounding from below $\lambda_{2}-\lambda_{1}$. (It is known that $\lambda_{1}$ is simple). Are there any known methods for this kind of problem?

Comment: Do you have any other information about A? As stated, the difference that you want to bound can be made arbitrarily small.

Comment: Well, $A$ is in fact a signless Laplacian of a graph. 

Comment: Searching google for "arbitrarily small spectral gap" produces this paper: <www.mis.mpg.de/fileadmin/jjost/abj21-6-04.pdf> which claims to construct graphs of arbitrarily small spectral gap given mild conditions on the degrees of the vertices. What is your starting point? If you know each entry of $A$ then you can presumably compute the eigenvalues and hence the gap. On the other hand if you want a theorem that bounds the gap for some general $A$, then there is no hope without more assumptions on the graph. 

Comment: One could get bounds depending on some feature of $A$. For instance, we all know that $a^2+b^2$ can get arbitrarily small for positive $a$ and $b$, but nevertheless it is interesting to discover the bound $2ab\leq a^2+b^2$. 

Comment: Vidit Nanda, OP is talking about the *signless* Laplacian, you are talking about the usual Laplacian, it seems. Their spectrum is quite different. For instance, it is known that the multiplicity of 0 as an eigenvalue of the signless Laplacian agrees with the number of connected components that are bipartite. In other words, if the graph is bipartite and connected, then OP's question simply reads: "Are there bounds on the second smallest eigenvalue?"

Answer (score 3):

You mention that $A$ is the Laplacian of a graph. The field of spectral graph theory is well established, and I think there are several techniques that can be used to bound the spectral gap of a graph Laplacian for an undirected weighted graph.

Perhaps the most straightforward is known as Cheeger's inequality which controls the spectral gap, $\lambda_2 - \lambda_1$ by the Cheeger constant of the graph.  See the wikipedia entry for Cheeger constant: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheeger_constant_(graph_theory)

If you might also consider trying a Log sobolev inequality:
http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.aoap/1034968224

I hope this helps.

Comment: But I am interested in the *signless* Laplacian - there is a Cheeger-type result for them (Desai & Rao, 1994) but I haven't seen anything for the gap. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

There are many articles on spectral theory for *signless* Laplacians $Q$, but the most complete is as far as I know [Towards a spectral theory of graphs based on the signless Laplacian, II](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0024379509002808/1-s2.0-S0024379509002808-main.pdf?_tid=d28b2d20-3d50-11e3-8b98-00000aacb35d&acdnat=1382690489_16b57163f2355932f6bccc0cb6732c2d)

In that paper, which is three years old, Cvetkovic and Simic point out why in their opinion not the second *smallest* is important, but the second *largest* $Q$-eigenvalue is important (hint: it corresponds to the spectral gap). Most researchers seem to share their opinion, because as far as I know the answer to your question is unknown.

The best available piece of information is, to my knowledge, the bound on the smallest $Q$-eigenvalues based on the largest (signed) Laplacian eigenvalue and the maximal and minimal degrees of the graph that is presented in [Bipartite subgraphs and the signless laplacian matrix](http://www.doiserbia.nb.rs/img/doi/1452-8630/2011/1452-86301100006K.pdf).

Comment: Thanks - I am familiar with these papers, though, and with this one too: http://arxiv.org/abs/1307.7749 :)